# Unwanted black frames around fog material

Tags: rendering, node-editor

So I was following this Tutorial; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72LPW4S8bns&t=1263s
then I was creating the fogs but suddenly the fog boxes that are further from camera started getting black corners. 
Im posting the nodes, please take a look
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and the solution to it is mentioned in the video you are linking to (appr. 20:10).

You have to increase the max bounces for **Transparency** under **Render Properties** / **Light Paths** / **Max Bounces** until the "black boxes" doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: Yes you are right Im sorry I was skipping the video to get it done faster, thanks :)